# Function to compare vowels existence in 2 strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a script of function comparing 2 strings and tells if the have the same vowels (both kind and number).

for example:

```
sameVowels('aabcefiok','xcexvcxaioa') should return `true`
```

and `sameVowels('aabcefiok','xcexvcxaioia')` should return `false`

Here is my try based on list. It doesnt work well and im not sure why; On this specific examples it returns `true` for both.

```
def sameVowels(s1, s2):
L1=[]
L2=[]
L_vowles=['a','e','i', 'o','u','A','E','I','O', 'U'] #dont know how to use str.upper/lower on lists...

for i in s1:
    if i in L_vowles:
        L1.append(i)
for i in s2:
    if i in L_vowles:
        L2.append(i)


for i in L1:
    L1.count(i)

for i in L2:
    L2.count(i)

return L1.count(i)== L2.count(i)
```

As you see i create some silly list - L_vowels...

I thought about using `sets` but i think it wont be useful since i cant use it for any kind of counting.

1.Whats wrong my my try?

2. any idea about solving it by using `dictionary`?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't follow your true/false logic. Can you explain a bit more? I'd take a look at `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first question

```
def sameVowels(s1, s2):
    L1=[]
    L2=[]
    L_vowles=['a','e','i', 'o','u','A','E','I','O', 'U'] #dont know how to use str.upper/lower on lists...

    for i in s1:
        if i in L_vowles:
            L1.append(i)
    for i in s2:
        if i in L_vowles:
            L2.append(i)
```

#### Your code was fine until here

From now on, it starts to make no sense. You wrote `LI.count(i)`, but that will do nothing. Then you compare `LI.count(i) == L2.count(i)` , which will only compare the count of the last value assigned to `i`, and not the count of all values i has assumed. In order to correct that, you should have something like this

```
    if (len(L1) == len(L2)):
        for i in L1:
            if (L1.count(i) != L2.count(i)):
                return false
        return true
    return false
```

That way, you'll have compared all values and return false in two cases: first, if the length of the lists are different, i.e. one of them has vowels the other does not have; second, if their count is different (I didn't actually understand why their count should be the same but it was your approach)

About the second question..

You can do it by building dictionaries that store the vowel as `key` and its count as `value`. Then, compare if both `dict`s built are equal.

Answer (score 5):

Just use generator expressions and sort:

```
def vowels(x):
    return (i for i in x if i.lower() in "aeiou")

def same_vowels(a, b):
    return sorted(vowels(a)) == sorted(vowels(b))
```

Comment: Nice. You might want to add support for uppercase characters (in `vowels`).

Comment: I meant if he calls with something like `same_vowels('AAA', 'III')`. As it stands now that would also be true. So how about `return (i for i in x if i.lower() in "aeiou")`?

Comment: @steinar correct I completely overlooked that, fixing

Comment: Im wondering what the first 'return' does.  I never saw for/if in return, and in particullar a statment starting in variable/counter before the for loop.what does the condition actually do? As i understand it it takes only the vowels, but i dont understand the use of i.lower()

Answer (score 2):

Lowercase both strings, filter them down to just the vowels, and then use `collections.Counter` and compare the results:

```
import collections
def same_vowels(s1, s2):
    return collections.Counter(letter for letter in s1.lower() if letter in 'aeiou'
      ) == collections.Counter(letter for letter in s2.lower() if letter in 'aeiou')
```

Result:

```
>>> same_vowels('aabcefiok','xcexvcxaioa')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, the count of each vowel also needs to be taken into consideration. Following is my take at it:

```
def getVowelsOf(s):
    vowels = set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])
    sVowels = {}
    for c in s.lower():
        if c in vowels:
            if c in sVowels:
                sVowels[c] = sVowels[c] + 1
            else:
                sVowels[c] = 1
    return sVowels

def sameVowels(s1, s2):
    s1Vowels = getVowelsOf(s1)
    s2Vowels = getVowelsOf(s2)
    return cmp(s1Vowels, s2Vowels) == 0
```